# Javascript: Uncaught SyntaxError: ambiguous indirect export: uuidv4

Tags: javascript, import

My script is imported like this in HTML:

```
page.html

...
<script type="module" src="{% static 'lib/uuid.min.js'  %}"></script>
<script type="module" src="{% static 'constants.js'  %}"></script>
...
```

The moduls "constants.js":

```
constants.js

import { uuidv4 as uuidv4 } from "./lib/uuid.min.js";

const action_name = "action_hello_world";
const url = "http://localhost:3423";
const sender = uuidv4();
```

But the browser's console shows the following error:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: ambiguous indirect export: uuidv4 constants.js
```

What is the error
Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Your probleme is It is exporting both a default export and a named export `uuidv4`.

To resolve this issue, you can import `uuidv4` as a default import like this:

```js
import uuidv4 from "./lib/uuid.min.js";

const action_name = "action_hello_world";
const url = "http://localhost:3423";
const sender = uuidv4();
```

Comment: Since we can't where they are exporting from, how do you know it's exporting both? I've seen the same error message in my own JS, but I don't have anything labeled as "default."

Comment: @XMehdi01 I changed it, now it throws (Uncaught SyntaxError: ambiguous indirect export: default). I'm importing from static files I'm integrating with Django. I installed the repo from github,the uuid module was provided by it.